# Adding a value in textbox to a value in a label

Tags: vba, label

I'm doing a project for coderdojo and I would like to know how to add a value inputted to a textbox named "depo" to a label called "balance" with the text of £0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a text box text change event 
Then use this code.

```
    Balance.Text = depo.Text;
```

You should try to search for questions similar to yours before asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is:

```
if depo.txt <> "" then balance.caption = "£" & depo.text
```